# Python 2.7 , issue with decode('utf-8')

Tags: python, utf-8

I have:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from urllib2 import urlopen

page2 = urlopen('http://pogoda.yandex.ru/moscow/').read().decode('utf-8')

page = urlopen('http://yasko.by/').read().decode('utf-8')
```

And in line "page ..." I have error "UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 32: invalid continuation byte", but in line "page2 ..." th error is not, why?

From a position of 32 in yasko.by starts  Cyrillic symbols, how I get it correctly?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The content of http://yasko.by/ is encoded with `windows-1251`, while the content of http://pogoda.yandex.ru/moscow/ is encoded with `utf-8`.

`page = ..` line should become:

```
page = urlopen('http://yasko.by/').read().decode('windows-1251')
```

Comment: and instead "<title>Главная</title>" I have "<title>\u041e\u0428\u0418\u0411\u041a\u0410</title>" with .decode('windows-1251')

Comment: @user2350206, Non-ascii characters are represented as u'\uxxxx' form in Python 2.x. Printing it will show you what you expected: `print(urlopen('http://yasko.by/').read().decode('windows-1251'))`